Best approach for recursion using OpenMP
I am parallelizing odd-even Merge Sort. But I only get worst results with the parallel approach than the sequential one.
void oddEvenMergeSort(int *arr, int n) {
    if (n > 1) {
        int m = n / 2;

        #pragma omp task shared(arr) // Crea una tarea para la primera mitad
        oddEvenMergeSort(arr, m);

        #pragma omp task shared(arr) // Crea una tarea para la segunda mitad
        oddEvenMergeSort(arr + m, n - m);

        // #pragma omp taskwait // Espera a que ambas tareas anteriores completen
        oddEvenMerge(arr, n);
    }
}

this is the way I use to parallelize the global function, and the result is the same than the sequential.
void oddEvenMerge(int *arr, int n) {
    if (n == 1) return;
    if (n == 2) {
        compare(arr, 0, 1);
        return;
    }
    else {
        int *odd = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n / 2));
        int *even = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n / 2));
        oddEvenSplit(arr, odd, even, n);
        
        // #pragma omp task shared(odd, even)
        oddEvenMerge(odd, n / 2);

        // #pragma omp task shared(odd, even)
        oddEvenMerge(even, n / 2);

        oddEvenJoin(arr, odd, even, n);

        for (int i = 1; i < n / 2; i++) {
            compare(arr, 2 * i - 1, 2 * i);
        }

        free(odd);
        free(even);
    }
}

here, if I use this omp task, it is even worse than the sequential.
void oddEvenSplit(int *arr, int *odd, int *even, int n) {
    // #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
        odd[i] = arr[2 * i + 1];
        even[i] = arr[2 * i];
    }
}

void oddEvenJoin(int *arr, int *odd, int *even, int n) {
    // #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
        arr[2 * i + 1] = odd[i];
        arr[2 * i] = even[i];
    }
}

finally, in this 2 functions i get as well worst results, but I suppose it is because they are a very simple loop so it is not worth it to parallelize it.

Without the #pragma omp taskwait, there is certainly a race condition in your code. This means an undefined behaviour (wrong results, crash, bad performance, etc.). Moreover,even with it, it seems there is a race condition : arr needs to be modified in both tasks. You must not do that. Instead, you should allocate a new array for the output so not to override it. Recycling array may result in better performance but you should first get a working version and only then optimize it.

By the way, please also share how do you measure the timings. It is not rare for benchmarks to be completely biased (like measuring the CPU time instead of the wall clock time).

double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    sort(arr, n);
    double end_time = omp_get_wtime();

I have already uncommented the taskwait, results are working, but is is the same time than the sequential.

Ok, the way to measure the timings seems correct to me. Is this code in a #pragma omp parallel section with a #pragma omp master or #pragma omp single? Outside of a section, tasks directives are ignored.

No. In the main I call the OddEvenMergeSort function and then there I implemented the tasks. I should then wrap it into a parallel section. Then, my problem is in if it is possible to paralelize the OddEvenMerge function. Also, I have thinked in only make tasks in the first k levels of recursion

Ok, i have implemented the parallel and single sections, and now I get some strange results. One out of 4 more or less, is much faster than the sequential one. But 3 out of 4 executions, are equal than the sequential one.

Certainly due to a race condition as explained above. Oh and you should really avoid having many very small tasks : you should not create tasks for small arrays (I think there is a if clause you can use)

You probably don't want to parallelize oddEvenSplit() and oddEvenJoin() as they are already running in parallel from the recursive tasks (at least for all but the first level of recursion).

Multi-threading with standard merge sort can greatly speed up sorting. Link to an old example: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025/
